# Keep the middle item centered when side items have different widths

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

[image]

Imagine the following layout, where the dots represent the space between the boxes:

```
[Left box]......[Center box]......[Right box]
```

When I remove the right box, I like the center box to still be in the center, like so:

```
[Left box]......[Center box].................
```

The same goes for if I would remove the left box.

```
................[Center box].................
```

Now when the content within the center box gets longer, it will take up as much available space as needed while remaining centered. The left and right box will never shrink and thus when where is no space left the `overflow:hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` will come in effect to break the content;

```
[Left box][Center boxxxxxxxxxxxxx][Right box]
```

All the above is my ideal situation, but I have no idea how to accomplish this effect. Because when I create a flex structure like so:

```
.parent {
    display : flex; // flex box
    justify-content : space-between; // horizontal alignment
    align-content   : center; // vertical alignment
}
```

If the left and right box would be exactly the same size, I get the desired effect. However when one of the two is from a different size the centered box is not truly centered anymore.

Is there anyone that can help me?

**Update**

A `justify-self` would be nice, this would be ideal:

```
.leftBox {
     justify-self : flex-start;
}

.rightBox {
    justify-self : flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Basically...you can't. That's not how `flexbox` is supposed to work. You might try another methodology.

Comment: Would really complete flexbox if it did tho. Cause flexbox is all about distributing space and how the items behave within.

Comment: We discussed `justify-self` earlier today, so you might find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/for-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties

Comment: Off topic, how did you make the animation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slightly more robust grid solution looks like this:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: orange;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(max-content, 1fr) auto minmax(max-content, 1fr);
}

.item > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: teal;
}

.item:last-child > div {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><div contenteditable>edit the text to test the layout</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div contenteditable>just click me and</div></div>
  <div class="item"><div contenteditable>edit</div></div>
</div>
```

And here you can see it in Codepen: https://codepen.io/benshope2234/pen/qBmZJWN

[image]

Comment: You sir. Solved it! This is the solution. To keep it within Grid I changed the last line to `.item:last-child > div { justify-self: end }` but this is preference.

Answer (score 266):

> If the left and right boxes would be exactly the same size, I get the desired effect. However when one of the two is a different size the centered box is not truly centered anymore. Is there anyone that can help me?

Here's a method using flexbox to center the middle item, regardless of the width of siblings.

Key features:

- pure CSS
- no absolute positioning
- no JS/jQuery

Use nested flex containers and `auto` margins:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box:first-child > span { margin-right: auto; }

.box:last-child  > span { margin-left: auto;  }

/* non-essential */
.box {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 40px;
}
p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"><span>short text</span></div>
  <div class="box"><span>centered text</span></div>
  <div class="box"><span>loooooooooooooooong text</span></div>
</div>
<p>&#8593;<br>true center</p>
```

Here's how it works:

- The top-level div (`.container`) is a flex container.
- Each child div (`.box`) is now a flex item.
- Each `.box` item is given `flex: 1` in order to distribute container space equally ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)).
- Now the items are consuming all space in the row and are equal width.
- Make each item a (nested) flex container and add `justify-content: center`.
- Now each `span` element is a centered flex item.
- Use flex `auto` margins to shift the outer `span`s left and right.

You could also forgo `justify-content` and use `auto` margins exclusively.

But `justify-content` can work here because `auto` margins always have priority.

> [**8.1. Aligning with `auto`
>   margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>
> Prior to alignment via `justify-content` and `align-self`, any
>   positive free space is distributed to auto margins in that dimension.

Comment: This solutions doesn't allow `width` to be specified

Comment: @AlexG, how so? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Changing the flexed elements' widths to distribute space evenly misses OP's question entirely. Their question has space between elements. Ex: "Imagine the following layout, where the dots represent the space between the boxes." Centering text in 3 evenly sized elements is trivial.

Comment: Respectfully disagree. There is space between *content*. Also the OP accepted the answer.

Comment: The OP also said "When I remove the right box, I like the center box to still be in the center, like so", how would you go about it without using a third empty column?

Comment: Could you explain the role of `flex: 1;` in more detail? I tried just setting flex-grow to 100 (100 is my standard value, just because I find it practical to divide if I need to), and it didn't work. I'm guessing it has something to do with flex being shorthand for `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` as well, but I'm still a little confused.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed for implementing MacOS-style window titlebars. Adding `white-space: nowrap` was the last piece of the puzzle to prevent text from wrapping when the area gets too small.

Answer (score 85):

1. Use three flex items in the container
2. Set `flex: 1` to the first and last ones. This makes them grow equally to fill the available space left by the middle one.
3. Thus, the middle one will tend to be centered.
4. However, if the first or last item has a wide content, that flex item will also grow due to the new `min-width: auto` initial value.

   Note Chrome doesn't seem to implement this properly. However, you can set `min-width` to `-webkit-max-content` or `-webkit-min-content` and it will work too.
5. Only in that case the middle element will be pushed out of the center.

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.item {
  background: lime;
  margin: 5px;
}
.left.inner-wrapper, .right.inner-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  min-width: -webkit-min-content; /* Workaround to Chrome bug */
}
.right.inner-wrapper {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.animate {
  animation: anim 5s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes anim {
  from { min-width: 0 }
  to { min-width: 100vw; }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="left inner-wrapper">
    <div class="item animate">Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="center inner-wrapper">
    <div class="item">Center</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right inner-wrapper">
    <div class="item">Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Analogous to above --> <div class="outer-wrapper"><div class="left inner-wrapper"><div class="item">Left</div></div><div class="center inner-wrapper"><div class="item animate">Center</div></div><div class="right inner-wrapper"><div class="item">Right</div></div></div><div class="outer-wrapper"><div class="left inner-wrapper"><div class="item">Left</div></div><div class="center inner-wrapper"><div class="item">Center</div></div><div class="right inner-wrapper"><div class="item animate">Right</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Excellent solution. However, I believe the style on the "Center" div could be removed since there's no matching CSS for "center inner-wrapper". @Oriol

Comment: This is a much better solution than the approved one. Setting ```flex: 1;``` on the left and right elements is all you need to do the trick.

Answer (score 83):

The key is to use `flex-basis`. Then the solution is simple as:

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.left, .right {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-basis: 0;
}
```

CodePen is available [here](https://codepen.io/gamliela/pen/BaLVrWg).

Comment: This answer works well and wraps the container's children for small screens.

Comment: This is by far the simplest and most workable answer here...

Comment: I must agree with previous comments. By far the easiest workable solution.

Comment: This works, but large left and right segments will still push the center segment out of alignment.

Comment: @Des this can be easily solved by adding `overflow: auto` to `.left` and `.right`.

Comment: @gamliela Thnx, I'll try it out.

Comment: This is perfect. If desired, `.left` and `.right` classes can be avoided by using `.parent > :first-child, .parent > :last-child` to set the flex grow and basis properties.

Answer (score 23):

Here's an answer that uses grid instead of flexbox. This solution doesn't require extra grandchild elements in the HTML like the accepted answer does. And it works correctly even when the content on one side gets long enough to overflow into the center, unlike the grid answer from 2019.

The one thing this solution doesn't do is show an ellipsis or hide the extra content in the center box, as described in the question.

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

section > *:last-child {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
}

/* not essential; just for demo purposes */
section {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: helvetica, arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 4px;
}

section > * {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>left</div>
  <div>center</div>
  <div>right side is longer</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div>left</div>
  <div>center</div>
  <div>right side is much, much longer</div>
</section>

<section>
  <div>left</div>
  <div>center</div>
  <div>right side is much, much longer, super long in fact</div>
</section>
```

Comment: This works.  I changed the `<section>` tag to `<div class="alignThreeColumn">` and use the class name in the CSS file instead of the `.section` tag name.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of defaulting to using flexbox, using grid solves it in 2 lines of CSS without additional markup inside the top level children.

HTML:

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="left">variable content</div>
  <div class="middle">variable content</div>
  <div class="right">variable content which happens to be very long</div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [first] 20% auto [last] 20%;
}
.middle {
  /* use either */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* or */
  text-align: center;
}
```

Flexbox rocks but shouldn't be the answer for everything. In this case grid is clearly the cleanest option.

Even made a codepen for your testing pleasure:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mooQOV

Comment: +1 for admitting that there may be other options than `flex` for everything. My only objection is that vertical alignment becomes easier using flex (`align-items: center`) in case your items are different heights and need to be aligned

Comment: I like this solution and the idea of using grid for this problem, but I think your solution has some notable drawbacks. First, if either of the outer cells' contents are larger than 20%, the content is either going to wrap or overflow into the center cell. Second, if the center is larger than 60%, it's going to grow outside of its content box and either wrap or push the last cell out. Finally, the center doesn't shift to make room for the outer cells. It just forces them to wrap/overflow. It's not a bad solution, but IMO, it's not "clearly the cleanest option".

Answer (score 8):

You can do this like so:

```css
.bar {
    display: flex;    
    background: #B0BEC5;
}
.l {
    width: 50%;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    display: flex;
}
.l-content {
    background: #9C27B0;
}
.m { 
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.m-content {    
    text-align: center;
    background: #2196F3;
}
.r {
    width: 50%;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.r-content { 
    background: #E91E63;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
    <div class="l">
        <div class="l-content">This is really long content.  More content.  So much content.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="m">
        <div class="m-content">This will always be in the center.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="r">
        <div class="r-content">This is short.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way to do it, using `display: flex` in the parents and childs:

```css
.Layout{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.Left{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
}
.Right{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'Layout'>
    <div class = 'Left'>I'm on the left</div>
    <div class = 'Mid'>Centered</div>
    <div class = 'Right'>I'm on the right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

I wanted the exact result shown in the question, I combined answers from gamliela and Erik Martín Jordán and it works best for me.

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.left, .right {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-basis: 0;
}

.right {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this simple way to reach exact center alignment for middle element :

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .sibling {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.container .sibling:first-child {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .sibling:last-child {
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 100px; /* .center's width divided by 2 */
}

.container .sibling:last-child .content {
    text-align: right;
}

.container .sibling .center {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/ErAz7/pen/mdeBKLG

Answer (score 0):

Althought I might be late on this one, all those solutions seems complicated and may not work depending on the cases you're facing.

Very simply, just wrap the component you want to center with `position : absolute`, while letting the other two with `justify-content : space-between`, like so :

CSS:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.middle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* You should adapt percentages here if you have a background ; else, left: 0 and right: 0 should do the trick */
  left: 40%;
  right: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* non-essential, copied from @Brian Morearty answer */
.element {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="element">First block</p>
  <p class="middle element">Middle block</p>
  <p class="element">Third THICC blockkkkkkkkk</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaner solution using grid layout, not nesting elements needed:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: orange;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  gap: 4px;
}

.item  {
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: teal;
}

.item:first-child {
  justify-self: start;
}

.item:last-child {
  justify-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">side</div>
  <div class="item">↓</div>
  <div class="item">side</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">long long long long long long</div>
  <div class="item">center center center</div>
  <div class="item">short short</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="item">short short short</div>
  <div class="item">center center center center</div>
  <div class="item">long long long long long</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick one [I made](https://jsfiddle.net/ultimatelifeform/9e2pnL4u/23/).

This is using `grid`. I mostly always use grid for this type of thing.
It makes it so much easier than to play with flex for all of the sub-items.

Basically you have:

```html
<div class="grid">
  <h1 class="center">Always center</h1>
  <button class="right">Right button</button>
</div>
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  // Place it so the layout looks like this: item --- item --- item
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "left center right";
  place-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.grid > * {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
  background-color: red;
}

.center {
  grid-area: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Basically you create a grid on the parent that holds the items and then you specify the layout using `grid-template-areas` and the item widths with `grid-template-columns`

Then you apply which item has which layout.

Example: The `.` in the layout is just a name but for simple sakes, I just put the name as a `.` just because it's unused.
Then I specify the `h1` to use the `text` layout by doing `grid-area: text;`.
The same with the button but I apply the right layout.

By doing it this way even if you delete a third item from the dom the center one will still be in true center because we did the 3 layout things by doing: `grid-template-areas: ". text button";`

The `.` is left.

The `center` is the center.

The `right` is right.

Don't forget to name the sub-items by applying `grid-area: <whatevername>;` so it goes together with your layout.

Sure you can just put a third empty div in there and just use regular flex but it clutters up the dom with unnecessary stuff so I prefer doing it this way.

Comment: This is not what I meant in the question. An element in the center should be in the center, but once the right element get's too large it will push the center element to the left. Which is not the case in your example. See the top green box in the animation.

Answer (score -1):

Michael Benjamin has a decent answer, but there is no reason it can't or shouldn't be simplified further.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box:first-child {
  justify-content: left;
}

.box:last-child {
  justify-content: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">short text</div>
  <div class="box">centered tex</div>
  <div class="box">looooooooooooooooooooooong text</div>
</div>
```