# Using 'order' property to position flex item between siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a flex-box with one to three flex-items.

The proper layout should look like `<div></div><h2></h2><div></div>` in the containing flex-box.

I have code to make this work (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028999/center-flex-item-in-container-when-surrounded-by-other-flex-items)) only if the layout order stays the same.

> My question is: how is there a way to make sure, if the markup is not always in that order (say one of my co-workers fails to do it correctly), how can I set it so that the `<h2>` always gets displayed in the middle (or as close as possible in the case that there are only one div and one h2).

To accomplish this I have been making use of the `order` property; however, I am either not using it to its full potential or it is the wrong solution.

I have made [this](https://jsfiddle.net/peb7eLv7/1/) jsfiddle as a testing ground for it but there is also this sample:

```
.diff-order {
  order: 2
}
.diff-order:not(h2) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > * {
  flex: 1;  /* KEY RULE */
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
h2 { 
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.container > div {
  display: flex;
}
.diff-order {
  order: 2
}
.diff-order:not(h2) {
  order: 1;
}
p { text-align: center;}
p > span { background-color: aqua; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
  <div>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="diff-order">
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
  <div class="diff-order">
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
  <div class="diff-order">
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What it accomplishes is it moves the `<h2>` to the end of the containing div. **I am trying to see if there is a way to set the order so that `<h2>` will always be the center item.** Maybe the pseudo-classes `:before` and `:after` can be utilized (maybe as replacements for the div's around the h2...).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are **three elements** in the container:

- div
- `h2`
- div

AND

- the order of these elements varies in the source...

AND

- you want the `h2` to always be in the middle...

THEN, you can do something like this:

```
.container > div:first-of-type { order: 1; }
.container > h2 { order: 2; }
.container > div:last-of-type { order: 3; }
```

This translates to:

> Regardless of the order of elements in the source,
>
> - The first div will appear first in the visual order
> - The `h2` will appear second in the visual order
> - The second div will appear last in the visual order

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > * {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
h2 { 
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.container > div:first-of-type { order: 1; }
.container > h2 { order: 2; }
.container > div:last-of-type { order: 3; }

p { text-align: center;}
p > span { background-color: aqua; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
  </div>
  <h2>I'm an h2</h2>
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 1</span>
    <span>I'm span 2</span>
    <span>I'm span 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 1</span>
    <span>I'm span 2</span>
    <span>I'm span 3</span>
  </div>
  <h2>I'm an h2</h2>
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 4</span>
    <span>I'm span 5</span>
    <span>I'm span 6</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 1</span>
    <span>I'm span 2</span>
  </div>
  <h2>I'm an h2</h2>
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <h2>
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
  <h2>
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="diff-order">
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
  <div class="diff-order">
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
  <div class="diff-order">
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
</div>
<p><span>TRUE CENTER</span></p>
```

---

For situations where there is **one element** in the container, add `justify-content: space-around`.

Because each item already has `flex: 1` applied, `space-around` will have no effect when there are two or more items in the container.

However, when there is only one item, `space-around` resolves to `center`.

*From the spec:*

> [**8.2. Axis Alignment: the `justify-content` property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-css-flexbox-1-20160301/#justify-content-property)
>
> The `justify-content` property aligns flex items along the main axis
>   of the current line of the flex container.
>
> > ***`space-around`***
> >
> > Flex items are evenly distributed in the line, with half-size spaces
> >     on either end.
> >
> > *If the leftover free-space is negative or there is
> >     only a single flex item on the line, this value is identical to
> >     `center`.*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; /* NEW */
}
.container > * {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
h2 { 
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.container > div:first-of-type { order: 1; }
.container > h2 { order: 2; }
.container > div:last-of-type { order: 3; }

p { text-align: center;}
p > span { background-color: aqua; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
  </div>
  <h2>I'm an h2</h2>
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 1</span>
    <span>I'm span 2</span>
    <span>I'm span 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 1</span>
    <span>I'm span 2</span>
    <span>I'm span 3</span>
  </div>
  <h2>I'm an h2</h2>
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 4</span>
    <span>I'm span 5</span>
    <span>I'm span 6</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 1</span>
    <span>I'm span 2</span>
  </div>
  <h2>I'm an h2</h2>
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <h2>
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
  <h2>
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="diff-order">
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
  <div class="diff-order">
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
  <div class="diff-order">
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="diff-order">
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
</div>
<p><span>TRUE CENTER</span></p>
```

You are now covered for ONE and THREE flex items.

For TWO items, it gets a bit trickier.

Since you always want the `h2` centered, I would suggest having two divs in the container at all times, even if they're empty. Then `flex: 1` will give all three items equal width.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.container > * {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
h2 { 
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.container > div:first-of-type { order: 1; }
.container > h2 { order: 2; }
.container > div:last-of-type { order: 3; }

p { text-align: center;}
p > span { background-color: aqua; padding: 5px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
  </div>
  <h2>I'm an h2</h2>
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 1</span>
    <span>I'm span 2</span>
    <span>I'm span 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 1</span>
    <span>I'm span 2</span>
    <span>I'm span 3</span>
  </div>
  <h2>I'm an h2</h2>
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 4</span>
    <span>I'm span 5</span>
    <span>I'm span 6</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 1</span>
    <span>I'm span 2</span>
  </div>
  <h2>I'm an h2</h2>
  <div>
    <span>I'm span 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <h2>
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
  <h2>
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="diff-order">
    I'm an h2
  </h2>
  <div class="diff-order">
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
  <div class="diff-order">
    <span>I'm a span</span>
    <span>I'm a span</span>
  </div>
</div>
<p><span>TRUE CENTER</span>
</p>
```