# How to always center the 3rd div in a row of 4 div's when wrap is enabled. It must stay centered when resizing the window

Tags: html, css

So I have 4 divs that are specific sizes. They are in a flex container that has flex-wrap set to 'wrap'. I need the 3rd div (blue) to always be in the center of the page. It needs to be in the center when resizing the window. The most ideal solution would also place the 3rd div (blue) in the top row when the window is resized so small that there are multiple rows, not sure if that's possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

[image: blue div should be centered]

[image: blue div should be centered]

[image: blue div should be centered and if possible placed on top row]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>RoutingTest</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center">|</div>
    <div
      style="
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        column-gap: 40px;
        row-gap: 10px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 0 20px;
      "
    >
      <div style="width: 274px; height: 40px; background-color: red"></div>
      <div style="width: 240px; height: 40px; background-color: green"></div>
      <div
        style="
          width: 340px;
          height: 40px;
          background-color: blue;
          color: white;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
        "
      >
        |
      </div>
      <div style="width: 474px; height: 40px; background-color: purple"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028999/center-flex-item-in-container-when-surrounded-by-other-flex-items - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948102/center-one-and-right-left-align-other-flexbox-element

Comment: Is there a reason the styling is inline? It makes it difficult to deal with media queries.

Comment: Could you show pictures of what it is to look like as the viewport gets smaller?