# Center middle flexbox item and justify the rest

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For an odd number of flex items I want the middle one to be in perfect center and other items just flow around it. The middle item has fixed width, all the rest are fluid and must stick to the middle item so the paddings are fixed.

[image]

```css
/* CSS */

.flex-holder {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
.middle-item {
 width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<ul class="flex-holder">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Some item</li>
  <li class="middle-item">Middle</li>
  <li>Very long text item</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Is it actually possible with flexbox? If no, please suggest another solution.

Comment: Try `space-between` or `space-around` for `justify-content`. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: It doesn't help to put the middle item in the perfect center.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. My question is comletely different. Someone didn't bother to read both questions...

Comment: I've read the other question, and that is exactly the same.

Comment: The linked duplicate answer is incorrect, here's the solution to OP's question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34406525/388994

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to use `position: absolute` on middle element and center it with `transform: translate()` but there will be overflow of elements on small window size which you can fix with media queries.

```css
.flex-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.middle-item {
  width: 75px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-holder">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Some item</li>
  <li class="middle-item">Middle</li>
  <li>Very long text item</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Another solution that will get result close to desired result is to wrap `li`'s left and right of middle li in `ul`'s and set `flex: 1` on them so they take equal size and set middle div always in center.

```css
ul, .wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0;
}
.middle-item {
  width: 75px;
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-holder">
  <li class="wrap">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Some item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="middle-item">Middle</li>
  <li class="wrap">
    <ul>
      <li>Very long text item</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way if the `middle-item` is in the middle (same number of items at rigth and left):

```css
.flex-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
}
.flex-holder li {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
li.middle-item {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-holder">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li class="middle-item">Middle</li>
  <li>Very long text item bla bla bla bla bla bla.</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

---

Also you can force to the middle nesting elements. For example:

```css
body {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/1x200) no-repeat center;
  }
  
  .flex-holder {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .flex-holder li {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid red;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 0 1em;
  }
  
  .flex-holder li div {
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 0 1em;
  }
  
  li.middle-item {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  li.middle-item ~ li {
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="flex-holder">
  <li>
    <div>Item 1 </div>
    <div> Some item</div>
  </li>
  <li class="middle-item">Middle</li>
  <li>
    <div>
      Very long text item </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The distance between all item must be the same. See my image

Comment: If you say space between the texts I think isn't possible, at least I don't know how you can do that

Comment: I edit my second snippet, I think it is pretty close  to what you want but maybe when there is not enought space don't work very well