# Center one element along with multiple siblings

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a div with some number of spans in it, that may or may not be of equal width.  I know I can use `text-align: center` to make all the content within a div be centered.  However, I want to pick a particular span, and designate that as the true center, rather than the center being the midpoint of the sequence of spans.

One idea I had to simulate this effect was: I'd have my desired middle element with two containers to its left and right; the left one would be right-justified, and vice-versa.  These containers would hold the other content in the div.  If I could get these two containers to fill up the remaining space in equal amounts, this would have the effect of centering the middle element while keeping the left and right content aligned with the center.  Basically, this would require the two containers' width to be set to exactly half the remaining space in the div.  (I don't want to change the size of the middle div.)  Is this possible to do with just CSS?

Example: with 4 spans, how to I designate span 2 as the true center?

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
#b {
  /* ??? */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="a">1</span>
  <span id="b">2</span>
  <span id="c">3</span>
  <span id="d">4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Lots of answers for an odd number (eg 3) of elements where the middle one is centered, but I'd be interested to see an elegant solution for an even number of elements ( eg 4) where the 2nd one is centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using flexbox.  You can use `display:flex;` on the `div`, and use `flex-grow:1;` on the `2nd span`. That way you can cover the whole div with that span.

Since the 1st and 3rd spans are already equal in width, you'll have the 2nd span in dead center. And then use `flex-basis` on the 2nd to get it's desired width.

```css
div.container{
  width: 500px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
div.row{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  transform:translate(50%,0);
}
#b {
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
      <span id="a">1</span>
      <span id="b">2</span>
      <span id="c">3</span>
      <span id="d">4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is sort of the inverse of this: span 2 takes up its natural width (or in this case, 100px) and the other two take up the remaining space in equal amounts.

Comment: @codebreaker   I think I managed to bring 2nd span in the center. See my updated answer

Comment: If it solves your problem please do accept my answer. if not then please tell me what addtion I have to do to my answer, because I got confused by your last comment.

Comment: That works, thanks.  I probably should have specified, though: the spans in the div may not be of equal length.  Is there a way this solution can be adapted to support spans of arbitrary size?

Comment: It will work great as long as all the span are of same size. after that only javascript can help. and please dont forget to accept the answer if it works in your case.

Comment: Sorry, in my question I proposed two ways to achieve the effect of "one element is in center, others are aligned with its left and right sides."  I thought that would help clarify what I was looking for, but maybe not.

Comment: ok. no problem , I'll work on a way to make this work on unequal width and if I find it I'll let you know.

Comment: I re-wrote my question to better explain what I'm trying to do, hopefully this helps.  Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34406525/1529630),

```css
.outer-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
.item {
  margin: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
.left.inner-wrapper, .right.inner-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  min-width: -webkit-min-content; /* Workaround to Chrome bug */
}
.left.inner-wrapper {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.animate {
  animation: anim 5s infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes anim {
  from { min-width: 0 }
  to { min-width: 50vw; }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="left inner-wrapper">
    <div class="item animate">1. Left</div>
  </div>
  <div class="center inner-wrapper">
    <div class="item">2. Center</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right inner-wrapper">
    <div class="item">3. Right</div>
    <div class="item">4. Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Analogous to above --> <div class="outer-wrapper"><div class="left inner-wrapper"><div class="item">1. Left</div></div><div class="center inner-wrapper"><div class="item animate">2. Center</div></div><div class="right inner-wrapper"><div class="item">3. Right</div><div class="item">4. Right</div></div></div><div class="outer-wrapper"><div class="left inner-wrapper"><div class="item">1. Left</div></div><div class="center inner-wrapper"><div class="item">2. Center</div></div><div class="right inner-wrapper"><div class="item animate">3. Right</div><div class="item">4. Right</div></div></div><div class="outer-wrapper"><div class="left inner-wrapper"><div class="item">1. Left</div></div><div class="center inner-wrapper"><div class="item">2. Center</div></div><div class="right inner-wrapper"><div class="item">3. Right</div><div class="item animate">4. Right</div></div></div>
```

This will attempt to center the desired element, but it will be pushed in case one side doesn't fit, to prevent overlapping.

Comment: Took me a minute to figure out what was going on in the animation, but that's really cool.  I thought flex boxes work based on whitespace, though, not width.  That's not what's going on here, is it?

Comment: @codebreaker The explanation is in the linked answer, I use three flex boxes which represent left, center, and right. The left and right ones are initially sized to 0 width and then they grow to fill remaining space, so the center one becomes centered. The implicit `min-width: auto` prevents overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do it with a 3 column layout, and use CSS table structure. Make the 1st and 3rd columns to take 50% of total width, and middle column will have only 0, but it will recalculate the width to fit the content and remains center since it's in a table.

Also put `white-space: nowrap;` there in case there are multiple words inside, but remove it as needed if there is only one word or fixed width.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.item-a {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
}
.item-b {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap; /* remove as needed */
}
.item-c {
  width: 50%;
}
.item span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.item-b span {
  padding: 0 50px; /* for demo only */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="item item-a">
    <span>1</span>
  </span>
  <span class="item item-b">
    <span>2</span>
  </span>
  <span class="item item-c">
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqm6zzas/)**