# Align my flex items left, middle and right

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I wanted the nav bar right at the top, to have the class with left on the left side, the class with middle right in the middle, and the class with right in the right side.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-container ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.flex-container nav ul .nytl {
  width: 189px;
  height: 26px;
}

.flex-container nav ul .first {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="left">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/16/000000/menu.png">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="left">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/16/000000/search.png">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="left"><a href="#">SPACE & COSMOS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="middle"><img src="https://lco1220.github.io/nyt_article/images/nyt-logo.png" alt="NewYorkTimes-Logo" class="nytl"></li>
      <li class="right"><button>Subscribe</button> .
      </li>
      <li class="right"><button>Login</button></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `auto` margins to push the left and right elements away from the middle element.

(Also, since you're using the HTML5 `nav` element and CSS3 properties, you really don't need a `ul` to structure your layout. You can simplify your code substantially.)

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav > * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nytl {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 189px;
  height: 26px;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/16/000000/menu.png">
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/16/000000/search.png">
  </a>
  <a href="#">SPACE & COSMOS</a>
  <img src="https://lco1220.github.io/nyt_article/images/nyt-logo.png" alt="NewYorkTimes-Logo" class="nytl">
  <button>Subscribe</button>
  <button>Login</button>
</nav>
<hr>
```

Learn more about `auto` margins here:

- [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Here's another flex method you may find useful:

- [Aligning Three Divs Horizontally Using Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32122011/3597276)

*You may encounter another problem now:* Because flex features such as `auto` margins, `justify-content` and `align-items` work by distributing free space, your middle item may not be perfectly centered. See these posts for more details and solutions:

- [Keep the middle item centered when side items have different widths](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32378953/3597276)
- [Center and right align flexbox elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38948102/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

I would utilise the `space-between` option that flex brings with the `justify-content` property. You have to be careful of the way the code is listed for SEO purposes as opposed to placing anywhere and have the `css` reposition it all. It should cascade in natural order first.

```css
.flex-thirds {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-thirds .col {
  width: 32%;
}

.nytl {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 189px;
  height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-thirds">
  <div class="col">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/16/000000/menu.png">
    </a>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/16/000000/search.png">
    </a>
    <a href="#">SPACE & COSMOS</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img src="https://lco1220.github.io/nyt_article/images/nyt-logo.png" alt="NewYorkTimes-Logo" class="nytl">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <button>Subscribe</button>
    <button>Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find more about `justify-content` here at [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)