# CSS Flexbox: element width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex `ul` with three `li`. The first and last `li` have contents of unknown and possibly differing length. The middle `li` should have its contents centered in the middle of the `ul`.

[image]

Is there any way to accomplish this with pure HTML/CSS?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

li:first-of-type {
  flex: 0;
}

li:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

li:last-of-type {
  flex: 0;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
  
  <ul>
    <li>Some Options</li>
    <li>Some long Title</li>
    <li>Done</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Will there only ever be three `<li>` elements? What should happen if a fourth, fifth, etc is added?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of [Keep the middle item centered…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378953/keep-the-middle-item-centered-when-side-items-have-different-widths). The image the asker posted shows that the three `li` items don’t have to be of equal width.

Comment: @DavidThomas yes, only three. It's like the menu at the top of an iOS Screen.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Just change the `flex` property in `li:first-of-type` to `1`. This simply means that you want that `li` element to expand.</s>

---

## Edit:

Since you want the middle `li` to be *centered* inside the `ul` the solution above won’t work. As far as I know, it is not possible to achieve this using pure CSS (please correct me if I’m wrong); use JavaScript instead. The cleanest way to do this is to make the first and the last `li` be of equal width:

```js
// select the first and last li
var first = document.querySelector("li:first-of-type");
var last = document.querySelector("li:last-of-type");

if(first.offsetWidth > last.offsetWidth) {
    // resize last li to width of first li
    last.style.width = first.offsetWidth + "px";
} else {
    // resize first li to width of last li
    first.style.width = last.offsetWidth + "px";
}
```

Also make sure that you remove the `flex` property from `li:first-of-type` and `li:last-of-type` in the CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I also feared that it might be impossible using CSS..

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a similar flex value to each li to make work.
the simpliest would be : `flex:1;` but `flex:1 1 auto;` works about too. a flex-basis , would work too but won't be flexible.

Demo below

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0;
    background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50% , rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%),linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50% , rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%);

}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

ul:first-of-type li {
  flex: 1;
}

hr~ul li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

li:first-of-type {}

li:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

li:last-of-type {
  text-align: right;
}

hr~hr~ul li {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

hr~hr~ul li:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) {
  max-width: 4em
}
```

```html
<p><code>flex:1;</code> result</p>
<ul>
  <li>Some Options</li>
  <li>Some long Title</li>
  <li>Done</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Some Options more</li>
  <li>Some long Title</li>
  <li>Done</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<p><code>flex:1 1 auto;</code> result</p>
<ul>
  <li>Some Options</li>
  <li>Some long Title</li>
  <li>Done</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Some Options more</li>
  <li>Some long Title</li>
  <li>Done</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<p><code>max-width</code> result</p>
<ul>
  <li>Some Options</li>
  <li>Some long Title</li>
  <li>Done</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Some Options more</li>
  <li>Some long Title</li>
  <li>Done</li>
</ul>
```

*I did not make any `flex-basis` example but a `max-width` and added the `flex:1 1 auto`; to show the difference it can make. i believe `flex:1;` is, the closest if not , the result you expect.*

---

You might also use flex:X with different values for the two outsider

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 0;
  /*see middle*/
  background:linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50% , rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%),linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50% , rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 50%);
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex:2;
}

li:first-of-type {

}

li:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

li:last-of-type {

  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Some Options</li>
    <li>Some long Title</li>
    <li>Done</li>
  </ul>
```

[image: screenshot from snippet]

Comment: Thanks, but in none of the results the Title is in the center of the `ul`

Comment: @TonaldDrump with **flex:1;** all 3 ul have the same width, so the one in the middle is in the middle. Anyway, there you have the few option of what you can do to make text-overlow effective, , pick up the one that makes the best compromise for you,, else , try manage this with javascript to reset the width for each lis on the fly. **And by the way, what browser(s) did you use testing the snippet ?** else you may also keep playin with the `flex` value (see  answer's update for another compromise)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this only works well when the outer elements are more or less this exact length. If they are very short, the middle element is abbreviated unnecessarily. I guess I'll go the Javascript route :) 
Tested on Safari btw

Comment: @TonaldDrump okay, thanks for the feed back, let us know how you solved it ;)