# What's the cleanest approach to position three nav elements symmetrically across the width of the page?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

This is my approach using **flexbox**, which creates asymmetry whenever one element is wider than the rest:

[image: Flexbox]

```html
<nav>
  <div>Logo</div>
  <div>Project Info</div>
  <div>Take me home</div>
</nav>
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

This is my approach using **absolute positioning**, which creates symmetry but doesn't respect line breaks in the center element:

[image: Absolute positioning]

```html
<nav>
  <div>Logo</div>
  <div class="center">Project Info</div>
  <div>Take me home</div>
</nav>
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;

  .center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378953/keep-the-middle-item-centered-when-side-items-have-different-widths

Comment: `nav div {width: 33%;}`