# TailwindCSS justity-between while ignoring child size

Tags: html, flexbox, tailwind-css

How can I position those child divs absolutely regardless of their size? Like middle should be at the middle regardless of its neighbors sizes.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex flex-row justify-between">
  <div>fsdf</div>
  <div>middle</div>
  <div>fsdfsdfsfsfsfsfsdfsfsdffsdfsfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsfsdfsdfdfsdfsfdsfs</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32378953/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grid` if you want consistency among them. Check out [Grid with equal width](https://play.tailwindcss.com/uARKRBgx46)

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3 break-words">
  <div class="col-span-1">fsdf</div>
  <div class="col-span-1">middle</div>
  <div class="col-span-1">fsdfsdfsfsfsfsfsdfsfsdffsdfsfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsfsdfsdfdfsdfsfdsfs</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `flex-1` to your items and also `break-all`

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex flex-row justify-between">
  <div class="flex-1 break-all">fsdf</div>
  <div class="flex-1 break-all">middle</div>
  <div class="flex-1 break-all">fsdfsdfsfsfsfsfsdfsfsdffsdfsfsfsdfsdfsdfsfsfsdfsdfdfsdfsfdsfs</div>
</div>
```